# What does $1_{\mathbb{R}}$ mean?

Tags: notation, fixed-point-theorems, contraction-operator

Please help. I can't understand the prove if I don't know what does $1_{\mathbb{R}}$ mean. Here is the example :

> For $a\in\mathbb{R}$, $|a|<1$ apply the Banach theorem to show that functional equation $f(x)=x+a\sin f(x)$ has unique solution $f\in C([0,1])$. Proof: Using uniform norm we have $F(h)=1_{\mathbb{R}}+a\sin h$, $F\in C([0,1])$. $d(F(h_1),F(h_2))=||F(h_1)-F(h_2)||...$

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here

$$\begin{align}
1_{\Bbb R}:\Bbb R & \to \Bbb R, \\
r & \mapsto r
\end{align}$$

is the identity function on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: This is definitely correct - do you know if this is common notation in analysis? When I've done analysis, $1_{\mathbb R}$ usually means an indicator function, not the identity. It's especially odd because the author is using a very specific notation, but $1_{\mathbb R}$ is not strictly in $C([0,1])$ since the domain is wrongly specified as $\mathbb R$ rather than $[0,1]$.

Comment: Other than in probability theory, it's standard to use $1_X$ (or sometimes $\text{id}_X$) as the identity function $X\to X$. Note that the indicator function is usually typeset as $\Bbb 1_X$.

Comment: I've seen what I suppose to be the indicator function defined by $$\chi_{\Bbb R}(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & : x\in\Bbb R, \\ 0 & : x\notin \Bbb R,\end{cases}$$ if that's what you mean. The use of $1_{\Bbb R}$ as the identity function is fairly standard in, say, category theory.